# Visual ASP.NET MVC Designer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, add-in

Is there an add-in for the VSIDE that allows you to visually construct ASP.NET MVC solutions?  Back in my struts days there were a number of options that made hooking together Views/Models/Controllers easy and interactive.

Comment: I dont know of one but cool thought

Comment: In ASP.NET MVC this is done with naming conventions, so what would the visual tool do?  Would it simply be a sophisticated renaming tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is tooling support in MVC tools for VS 2008/2010 which helps in performing common tasks, such as
Add Area, 
Add Controller,
Add View,
Go To View,
etc
...

they all use current context when creating artifacts. For example, when you are using "Add View" you can choose to create strongly typed view and perform operation you want (CRUD) over Model data passed to it.

Not 100% visual in a way that you can draw diagram of controllers, views and models and hook them together.

Not sure if this answers your question but if you are familiar with the tools, it will probably be helpful to others.

Comment: I agree this exsits, but I'm think more about a visual way to plug everything together.  You could see the relationship between the various Views/Controllers ... the types flowing around.  Set Attrbiutes interactively.